# How to automate copying code of multiple html files?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I apologize in advance if this is a basic kind of question.

I have thousands of html files inside multiple sub-directories. I want to be able to copy the code of each individual html file into a new one, preferably with the same name.

I have been able to do the same via batch command but only for a single file.
It goes like this:

`type index.html > new.html`

This command also works if I change it to : `type *.html > new.html`
But, the problem is that it copies the code of all the html files in the folder to the *new.html* file (as expected).

So, is there any way to automate this whole process? I'm not looking for a way to copy all the files, instead create a new html extension file and copy the code one by one.

Comment: Your requirement makes no sense, a simple copy would perform exactly what you are doing except it would maintain the file attributes also. You can copy a file to a new filename simply by specifying it `copy source.txt dest.html`.

Comment: There is a reason I'm asking for this. The existing html files have some user privilege issues and editing them is really difficult, and makes the whole project act weird.
I don't face the same issues when I copy the html code.